# number of rows each data frame in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames in R. They are created using lapply and read.csv commands. I want to know the number of rows of each data frame in the list. The nrow command does not work for this list. I am not sure may because it is a list. Any idea about counting the number of rows of each data frame in a list?

Comment: Can you supply the code you used to generate the list of dataframes?

Answer (score 16):

Lists don't have rows.  Use `sapply` to loop over the list:

```
sapply(data.frame.list, nrow)
```

Answer (score 2):

or lapply-   the difference is in the output

```
lapply(data.frame.list, function(x) nrow(x))
```

Comment: There is no need to define a new (anonymous) function.